# Replacing single elements in list

Tags: list, haskell, higher-order-functions, partial-application

So, I am currently doing an exercise where I have a list of employees, with the data type *Employee*.

```
data Employee = Employee Name Age Salary deriving (Show)

employees :: [Employee]
employees =
  [ Employee "Alice" 28 50000.0,
    Employee "Bob" 35 60000.0,
    Employee "Charlie" 42 75000.0,
    Employee "David" 30 55000.0,
    Employee "Eva" 25 48000.0
  ]
```

I am supposed to write a function *mapEmployee :: (Name -> Name) -> (Age -> Age) -> (Salary -> Salary) -> Employee -> Employee* with the form *mapEmployee n a s e = (function)* that can replace the name, age and salary of a given entry.

We are supposed to use 3 functions for this, so I take it that I should write 3 helper functions that I then use in *mapEmployee*.

As a prior part of the exercise, I already defined functions getName, getAge and getSalary, which alll follow this shape:

```
getName :: Employee -> Name
getName (Employee n _ _) = n
```

However, I don't understand functional programming enough to make the connection of how to use them in this context. I have thought about using a filter-function to look for an index number and simply replace the whole Employee-type entry, instead of trying to alter single values within Employee-records, however I have had no success in trying to filter for the index yet, let alone replace the name, age or salary once I get this far.

Comment: `mapEmployee` as you describe it has nothing to do with lists. It is just about changing the fields of a single `Employee` data type.

Comment: I see you have kind of an idea already. Here's a hint: `mapEmployee f g h (Employee name age salary) = ...`. Complete the dots.  Remember `f`, `g` and `h` are functions transforming each field of the employee.

Comment: For reference, here's how you increase the age of an employee `incrAge (Employee name age salary) = Employee name (age+1) salary`. Your task is a variation on this theme.

Comment: An alternate implementation of `incrAge` that may also be enlightening is this one: `incrAge e = Employee (getName e) (getAge e + 1) (getSalary e)`.